# codingbat python string count

Tags: python, string

Return True if the string "cat" and "dog" appear the same number of times in the given string.

This is the question I'm attempting. my code is:

```
def cat_dog(str):
    count1 = 0
    count2 = 0
   
    if 'dog' and 'cat' not in str:
        return True
    for i in range(len(str)-1):
        if str[i:i+3] == 'cat':
            count1 += 1
        if str[i:i+3] == 'dog':
            count2 += 1
    if count1 == count2:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

i know this is incorrect as the code does not seem to be looping through the whole string and picking up cat and dog. not sure how to rectify this.

Comment: I wouldn't use str as a variable name, as it is a class name, so you can not use that class in the function. I would use `string` or `str_` .

Comment: _`if 'dog' and 'cat' not in str:`_ See https://stackoverflow.com/q/15112125.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `count` method to count the number of occurrences of a string.

```
>>> 'catdog'.count('cat') == 'catdog'.count('dog')
True
>>> 'catdogdog'.count('cat') == 'catdogdog'.count('dog')
False
>>>
```

You need to add a condition before this code otherwise the above code should return `true` if both `cat` or `dog` does not exists on the input string.

```
if 'dog' in string or 'cat' in string:
    return string.count('cat') == string.count('dog')
```

Comment: `count` doesn't count overlapping matches that the OP's code would  - eg `banana.count("ana") == 1`. Not that it makes a difference for "cat" and "dog"

Answer (score 1):

This could work:

```
def cat_dog(str):
  counter_cat = 0
  counter_dog = 0
  for i in range(0, len(str)-2):
    if str[i] == 'c' and str[i+1] == 'a' and str[i+2] == 't':
      counter_cat += 1
    elif str[i] == 'd' and str[i+1] == 'o' and str[i+2] == 'g':
      counter_dog += 1
  return counter_cat == counter_dog
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def cat_dog(str):
    count_of_cat = str.count("cat") 
    count_of_dog = str.count("dog")
    if count_of_cat == count_of_dog:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a one line solution:

```
return str.count('cat') == str.count('dog')
```

this block of code is not needed is this case

```
if 'dog' and 'cat' not in str:
    return True
```

simply beacause you intialize count1 and count2 to 0 then if no dog or cat in word they are equal, they don´t increment

also in this block of code

```
if count1 == count2:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

you can reduce to this

```
return count1 == count2
```

it will see the boolean values for that expression
return true if count1 == count2 else return false

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
if 'dog' and 'cat' not in str:
```

This doesn't do what you think it does. Python interprets it like this:

```
if ('dog') and ('cat' not in str):
```

The first part is always true, because `'dog'` is a non-empty string, so it comes down to `'cat' not in str`. So you are really only checking to see if the string doesn't contain `'cat'`.

You want something like this:

```
if 'dog' not in str and 'cat' not in str:
```

Or, equivalently:

```
if not ('dog' in str or 'cat' in str):
```

Or, if you have more tests to make, this is more compact for more than a couple:

```
if not any(x in str for x in ('cat', 'dog', 'mouse', 'beaver')):
```

This will affect whether the function even gets to the loop, so it is probably throwing you off.

Also, don't name your variable `str`. `str` is a built-in type, and you might need to use it, but can't because you've reassigned it.

Comment: yes. codingbat uses str as a variable name so you're kind of forced to use it. thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

The part where you `return` from the function should not be inside the `for` loop. This is why the loop is exiting prematurely for you

```
def cat_dog(str):
    count1 = 0
    count2 = 0

    if 'dog' not in str and 'cat' not in str: # <= kindall pointed this out
        return True

    for i in range(len(str)-1):
        if str[i:i+3] == 'cat':
            count1 += 1
        if str[i:i+3] == 'dog':
            count2 += 1

    if count1 == count2:  # <= These shouldn't be part of the for loop
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

The last 4 lines should normally be written as

```
    return count1 == count2
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code just has 2 minute mistakes. Once rectified, it gives perfect results without any further changes. Check below.

Edit1 in line8:
Instead of "for i in range(len(str)-1):", it needs: "for i in range(len(str)-2):" - As the words cat and dog both are 3 letter words and for capturing every single combination making "cat" and "dog", we need to count from 3rd last letter. hence "-2" instead of "-1"

Edit2 in lines 12,13,14,15:
Indentation is incorrect. It compares the count1 and count2 immediately after the first iteration of value i and hence returns wrong results. Just correct indentation and your code is perfect to go!

Check the corrected code without any additional inputs from my end.

```
def cat_dog(str):
    count1 = 0
    count2 = 0

    if 'dog' and 'cat' not in str:
        return True
    for i in range(len(str)-2):
        if str[i:i+3] == 'cat':
            count1 += 1
        if str[i:i+3] == 'dog':
            count2 += 1
    if count1 == count2:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    def cat_dog(str):

       cat = dog = 0
  
       for i in range(len(str)-2):
          if str[i:i+3] == "cat":
             cat += 1
          if str[i:i+3] == "dog":
             dog += 1
       return cat == dog
```

Comment: Please explain to the OP what was wrong with their code, rather than just posting a working version.